# $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{x+k} - \frac{1}{x-k})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a closed form for this sum $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{x+k} - \frac{1}{x-k})$$

Based on a recent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343557/335418) that Felix Marin posted to my question, this is what I got:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (H_{x+n} - H_{-x+n}) - (H_{x-1} - H_{-x-1})$$

I am new to this and don't know how to proceed. Any help? I have a feeling that FM's answer already has a solution to this, but I am just not able to get there.

Comment: your series diverges

Comment: But can it be expressed something like an impulse train (dirac-delta comb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Harmonic number function is $H_x$ then the sum is
$$-H_{-x}-H_x+2 \gamma$$
Shifting the index by one we have
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{k+x+1}+\frac{1}{k-x+1}\right)$$
Using digamma $\psi$ function we have
$$-\psi(x+1)-\psi(-x+1)=-H_{-x}-H_x+2 \gamma$$

see
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Regularization)